# JavaScript Dynamic Synchronous Functions Queue

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Below is the problem description I am trying to solve in JavaScript for an SAPUI5 application.

1. User press Enter on the UI and there is oData call(Async Post) to
   the backend which is wrapped in a function with blocking one part of
   the screen.
2. While the first async call is in progress, User can
   press enter and send another OData Call by the wrapper function.
3. There can be multiple calls to the backend which is dynamic as per the user interaction on the UI.

My requirement is to sequence the calls one after the another only i.e. when first call is completed then send the second call and so on. While the user takes time between UI interactions the call(s) which are queued can be in progress or completed.

Please suggest!

Thanks,
Venkat.

Comment: Using a queue sounds like a good idea. Have you tried it? Please show us the code you tried.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a example, a code snippet . We will not write code for you from scratch.
Also worth reading is the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I haven't tried queue. any sample code? Thanks!

Comment: I have tried using array of promises but as the array is a dynamic one, I was not able to chain them one after the another.